# How to calculate perplexity of RNN in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm running the word RNN implmentation of tensor flow of [Word RNN](https://github.com/hunkim/word-rnn-tensorflow)

How to calculate the perplexity of RNN.

Following is the code in training that shows training loss and other things in each epoch:

```
for e in range(model.epoch_pointer.eval(), args.num_epochs):
        sess.run(tf.assign(model.lr, args.learning_rate * (args.decay_rate ** e)))
        data_loader.reset_batch_pointer()
        state = sess.run(model.initial_state)
        speed = 0
        if args.init_from is None:
            assign_op = model.batch_pointer.assign(0)
            sess.run(assign_op)
            assign_op = model.epoch_pointer.assign(e)
            sess.run(assign_op)
        if args.init_from is not None:
            data_loader.pointer = model.batch_pointer.eval()
            args.init_from = None
        for b in range(data_loader.pointer, data_loader.num_batches):
            start = time.time()
            x, y = data_loader.next_batch()
            feed = {model.input_data: x, model.targets: y, model.initial_state: state,
                    model.batch_time: speed}
            summary, train_loss, state, _, _ = sess.run([merged, model.cost, model.final_state,
                                                         model.train_op, model.inc_batch_pointer_op], feed)
            train_writer.add_summary(summary, e * data_loader.num_batches + b)
            speed = time.time() - start
            if (e * data_loader.num_batches + b) % args.batch_size == 0:
                print("{}/{} (epoch {}), train_loss = {:.3f}, time/batch = {:.3f}" \
                    .format(e * data_loader.num_batches + b,
                            args.num_epochs * data_loader.num_batches,
                            e, train_loss, speed))
            if (e * data_loader.num_batches + b) % args.save_every == 0 \
                    or (e==args.num_epochs-1 and b == data_loader.num_batches-1): # save for the last result
                checkpoint_path = os.path.join(args.save_dir, 'model.ckpt')
                saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step = e * data_loader.num_batches + b)
                print("model saved to {}".format(checkpoint_path))
    train_writer.close()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The project you are referencing uses `sequence_to_sequence_loss_by_example`, which returns the cross-entropy loss. So for calculating the training perplexity, you just need to exponentiate the loss like explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perplexity).

```
train_perplexity = tf.exp(train_loss)
```

We have to use e instead of 2 as a base, because TensorFlow measures the cross-entropy loss with the natural logarithm ([TF Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits)). Thank you, @Matthias Arro and @Colin Skow for the hint.

## Detailed Explanation

The cross-entropy of two probability distributions P and Q tells us the minimum average number of bits we need to encode events of P, when we develop a coding scheme based on Q. So, P is the true distribution, which we usually don't know. We want to find a Q as close to P as possible, so that we can develop a nice coding scheme with as few bits per event as possible.

I shouldn't say bits, because we can only use bits as a measure if we use base 2 in the calculation of the cross-entropy. But TensorFlow uses the natural logarithm, so instead let's measure the cross-entropy in **nats**.

So let's say we have a bad language model that says every token (character / word) in the vocabulary is equally probable to be the next one. For a vocabulary of 1000 tokens, this model will have a cross-entropy of *log(1000) = 6.9 nats*. When predicting the next token, it has to choose uniformly between 1000 tokens at each step.

A better language model will determine a probability distribution Q that is closer to P. Thus, the cross-entropy is lower - we might get a cross-entropy of 3.9 nats. If we now want to measure the perplexity, we simply exponentiate the cross-entropy:

*exp(3.9) = 49.4*

So, on the samples, for which we calculated the loss, the good model was as perplex as if it had to choose uniformly and independently among roughly 50 tokens.

Comment: the train loss is 6.3 in my case,  so you are saying that the train perplexity will be 2^6 =  64?

Comment: @ShanKhan yes. Your model is as confused on the training data as if it had to choose randomly between 64 options for each word.

Comment: I believe 'exponentiate' means an exponential of e (e^x), not a power of 2. From my research the correct calculation is:
train_perplexity = tf.exp(train_loss)

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether your loss function gives you a log likelihood of the data in base 2 or base e. This model is using legacy_seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example, which uses TensorFlow's binary crossentropy, which [appears to use logs of base e](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent). Therefore, even though we're dealing with a discrete probability distribution (text), we should exponentiate with e, i.e. use tf.exp(train_loss) as Colin Skow suggested.