# Keras loss function value error: ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. on LSTM network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

So I'm trying to train my LSTM network language model, and use a perplexity function as my loss function but i get the following error:

```
ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

My loss function looks as follows:

```
from keras import backend as K
def perplexity_raw(y_true, y_pred):
    """
    The perplexity metric. Why isn't this part of Keras yet?!
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881308/how-to-calculate-perplexity-of-rnn-in-tensorflow
    https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8267
    """
#     cross_entropy = K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    cross_entropy = K.cast(K.equal(K.max(y_true, axis=-1),
                          K.cast(K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1), K.floatx())),
                  K.floatx())
    perplexity = K.exp(cross_entropy)
    return perplexity
```

and I create my model as follows:

```
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 500, input_length=max_length-1))
model.add(LSTM(750))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
print(model.summary())
# compile network
model.compile(loss=perplexity_raw, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit network
model.fit(X, y, epochs=150, verbose=2)
```

The error occurs  when I try to fit my model. Does anyone know what causes the error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the culprits: `K.argmax` and `K.max`. They don't have a gradient. I also think you just straight up don't need them in your loss metric! That's because `max`ing and `argmax`ing something removes the information on *how much* the prediction is wrong.

I don't know what kind of loss you want to measure, but I think you are looking for something like `tf.exp(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_true, y_pred))` or `tf.exp(tf.softmax_cross_entopy_with_logits(y_true, y_pred))`. You might need to convert your logits to one hot encodings using `tf.one_hot`.

Comment: Thanks that helped, but how would I call my logits to encode them?