# Keras: How to one-hot encode logits to match labels for loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to implement a perplexity loss function for my LSTM language model. However I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,3345] and labels shape [107040]
     [[{{node loss_9/dense_10_loss/perplexity/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]]
```

Now, I think the way to solve this is by one-hot encoding my logits, but I'm not sure how to do this, i.e. I don't know how to access my logits, and I dont know what depth I should encode them with.

My loss function looks as follows:

```
import keras.losses
from keras import backend as K
def perplexity(y_true, y_pred):
    """
    The perplexity metric. Why isn't this part of Keras yet?!
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881308/how-to-calculate-perplexity-of-rnn-in-tensorflow
    https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8267
    """
    cross_entropy = K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    perplexity = K.exp(cross_entropy)
    return perplexity
```

And I define my LSTM model as follows:

```
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 500, input_length=max_length-1))
model.add(LSTM(750))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
print(model.summary())
# compile network
model.compile(loss=perplexity, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit network
model.fit(X, y, epochs=150, verbose=2)
```

Comment: I think you are looking for https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use sparse_categorical_crossentropy your output must be simply integer encoded

```
def perplexity(y_true, y_pred):
    cross_entropy = K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    perplexity = K.exp(cross_entropy)
    return perplexity

vocab_size = 10
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (1000,10))
y = np.random.randint(0,vocab_size, 1000)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=(10)))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
# compile network
model.compile(loss=perplexity, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit network
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, verbose=2)
```

if you have one-hot encoded target, take care to change `K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy` in `K.categorical_crossentropy`

```
def perplexity(y_true, y_pred):
    cross_entropy = K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    perplexity = K.exp(cross_entropy)
    return perplexity

vocab_size = 10
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (1000,10))
y = pd.get_dummies(np.random.randint(0,vocab_size, 1000)).values # one-hot

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=(10)))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
# compile network
model.compile(loss=perplexity, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit network
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, verbose=2)
```

Comment: Thank you! it turned out I only had to change to ```K.categorical_crossentropy```